# Getting null descendants using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm calling a web service and using `Webresponse.GetResponseStream` to get the XML below.

I'm having no luck using `Linq-to-XML` to get the `<Item`> and `<Title>` elements. I'm getting `null` back when using `Descendants`.

Can someone suggest what I can try to get these elements?

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
 <Items>
<Request>
  <IsValid>True</IsValid>
  <ItemSearchRequest>
    <ResponseGroup>Small</ResponseGroup>
    <SearchIndex>DVD</SearchIndex>
    <Title>Jaws</Title>
  </ItemSearchRequest>
</Request>
<Item>
  <ASIN>B007STBUIW</ASIN>
  <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/Jaws-Blu-ray-Digital-Copy-UltraViolet/dp/B007STBUIW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIR3KWWR37IS5MTBA%26tag%3Dfli048-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB007STBUIW</DetailPageURL>
  <ItemLinks>
    <ItemLink>
      <Description>Technical Details</Description>
      <URL>http://www.amazon.com/Jaws-Blu-ray-Digital-Copy-UltraViolet/dp/tech-data/B007STBUIW%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIR3KWWR37IS5MTBA%26tag%3Dfli048-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007STBUIW</URL>
    </ItemLink>
    <ItemLink>
      <Description>Add To Baby Registry</Description>
      <URL>http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/baby/add-item.html%3Fasin.0%3DB007STBUIW%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAIR3KWWR37IS5MTBA%26tag%3Dfli048-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB007STBUIW</URL>
    </ItemLink>
  </ItemLinks>
  <ItemAttributes>
    <Actor>Roy Scheider</Actor>
    <Creator Role="Writer">Carl Gottlieb</Creator>
    <Director>Steven Spielberg</Director>
    <Title>Jaws (Blu-ray + DVD + Digital Copy + UltraViolet)</Title>
  </ItemAttributes>
</Item>
<Item>
  <ASIN>B008YKB3X6</ASIN>
  <DetailPageURL>http://www.amazon.com/Jaws-Comes-Home-HD/dp/B008YKB3X6%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIR3KWWR37IS5MTBA%26tag%3Dfli048-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB008YKB3X6</DetailPageURL>
  <ItemLinks>
    <ItemLink>
      <Description>Technical Details</Description>
      <URL>http://www.amazon.com/Jaws-Comes-Home-HD/dp/tech-data/B008YKB3X6%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIR3KWWR37IS5MTBA%26tag%3Dfli048-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3DB008YKB3X6</URL>
    </ItemLink>
  </ItemLinks>
  <ItemAttributes>
    <Creator Role="Producer">Discovery</Creator>
    <ProductGroup>TV Series Episode Video on Demand</ProductGroup>
    <Title>Jaws Comes Home [HD]</Title>
  </ItemAttributes>
</Item>
  </Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

Update:

Thanks Jim and Kelly that was the issue.  I am now able to get the  value using this code :

```
var itemtitle = doc2.Root.Element(ns + "Items").Elements(ns +     "Item").Elements(ns + "ItemAttributes").Elements(ns + "Title").First();
```

Comment: You need to specify your XML Namespace in the LINQ. Please include your LINQ code if you want additional help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim said, adding the namespace should work. Here is an example to pull the items.

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
XNamespace ns = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01";
var items = xml.Root.Element(ns+"Items").Elements(ns+"Item");
```

Comment: I updated the original post above with an "Update" rather than here as the code doesn't format correctly..

Comment: @JimWooley Not a problem - I  feel bad though because you deserve the answer credit!